# Square brackets after object creation

Tags: javascript, object

I have a problem with the following code:

```
// At the beginning
var prog = {}
// some attributes of prog and other methods
// ...

prog.stateChange = function(state)
{
    var functionOfState =
    {
        onState1: function()
        {
           // some code
        },

        onState2: function()
        {
            // some code
        } 
    }['on'+state]()
}
```

Which purpose have these square brackets after the creation of the object functionOfState? Is this an array of possible methods?

Sorry, I'm a total newbie in JS and I haven't found any information about this.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Such an interesting usage :)

Comment: Note: _"interesting"_ doesn't necessarily mean "good".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does *almost* the same as:

```
var functionOfState =
{
    onState1: function()
    {
       // some code
    },

    onState2: function()
    {
        // some code
    } 
}

functionOfState['on'+state]();
```

It simply creates an object which stores different functions. Then, it calls one of them according to the current value of `state`.

Maybe, this one will be even easier:

```
var functionOfState = {};

functionOfState['onState1'] = function() { 
    // someCode
};

functionOfState['onState2'] = function() { 
    // someCode
};

functionOfState['on'+state](); // when state is 'State2', 'onState2' will be called
```

The difference that in your code it doesn't store this object with functions, but calls it directly.

Comment: Instead of `functionOfState['onState1']`, I'd use `functionOfState.onState1`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand. Is this a self-invoke method, because it is directly called?

Comment: @escape: In short, the variable `functionOfState` will contain the _returned value_ from a function, chosen with the `state` parameter. So, if `state === 'State1'`, then `functionOfState` will contain whatever `onState1` _returns_.

Comment: @Cerbrus Okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is (not the most clear)  way to extract field from an object.
in JS, the subscript operator (`[]`) can extract a property out of an object just like the dot operator (`.`), so the following expressions are equal:

```
var obj = { field : value };
obj.field == obj["field"]; //returns true
```

on your example an object with the fields `onState1`, `onState2` is created. then, using the subscript operator the correct property is extract. it is equivilant on writing

```
prog.stateChange = function(state)
{

    var temp = 
    {
        onState1: function()
        {
           // some code
        },

        onState2: function()
        {
            // some code
        } 
    };
  var functionOfState = state == onState1 ? temp.onState1 : temp.onState2;
  functionOfState();
}
```

This is not a legit way to extract a property/method out of an object. basically if someone changes the name of the method, the code breaks. it is much better to simply use a switch case.

Comment: The code you provided is not equivalent. Your code completely ignores the `state` parameter.

Comment: I find downvotes to be more efficient. It's still not quite equivalent: `var functionOfState = temp['on'+state]();`